# What groups have a homomorphic image $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

> Is there a simple characterization for all the groups $G$ so that there exists an epimorphism $\varphi:G\to\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$?

First assume there exists a nontrivial homomorphism $\varphi:G\to\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$. Denote $K=\operatorname{ker}(\varphi)$ and $H=\varphi^{-1}(1)=G\setminus K$. I understand that any such group must have the following properties:

1. $G/K\cong\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$.
2. If $a,b\in H$ and $x\in K$, then $ab\in K$ (since $\varphi(ab)=\varphi(a)+\varphi(b)=1+1=0$) and similarly $ax\in H$.

Is there a more complete characterization of such groups?

**Edit:** I extend my previuos question and ask the following:

> Is there a characterization of all groups $G$ such that there exists a nontrivial homomorphism $\varphi:G\to\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ for a given $n\in \Bbb{N}$?

Comment: All subgroups of index $2$ are normal, so this happens iff $G$ has a subgroup of index $2$.

Comment: So the first direction is proved in my question, and the other direction can be shown by defining, assuming $N$ is a (normal) group of index $2$, a homomorphism sending $x$ to $0$ if $x\in N$ and to $1$ otherwise?

Comment: what does "homomorphic" mean?

Comment: @ElliotG, That there exists a homomorphism (of groups) between the two groups.

Comment: Does that include nontrivial maps $\Bbb Z/2\to G$?

Comment: @ElliotG, groups with a nontrivial homomophism $G\to\Bbb{Z}/2$.

Comment: sounds like your asking about the group extension problem.

Comment: @Connor, Where can I read about this problem and its connection to my question?

Comment: Your terminology is non-standard and confusing: we don't say $G$ is homomorphic to $H$ if there is a homomorphism from $G$ to $H$. In standard terminology, you are asking  "what groups $G$ have $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ as a homomorphic image?".

Comment: @RobArthan, thank you, I changed it.

Comment: Some random comments: If $G$ is finite then must have even order. There is a classical exercise that if $|G|$ is not divisible by $4$ then it must have a subgroup of index $2$. But this doesn't hold for every finite group of even order. For example $A_4$ has no subgroup of index $2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be phrased as a special case of the [group extension problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension): you are asking for a classification of extensions of the form

$$1 \to H \to G \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to 1.$$

The very simplest examples occur when $G \cong H \times \mathbb{Z}_2$; these are just classified by groups $H$. The next simplest occur when the extension splits, meaning $G$ is a [semidirect product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product) $H \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$; these are classified by pairs of a group $H$ and an action of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ on $H$, more explicitly an involution $\varphi : H \to H$ (an automorphism that squares to the identity), up to conjugation by automorphisms of $H$.

The general case is when the extension does not split. This happens already for $G = \mathbb{Z}_4$. I actually don't know a reference that clearly states the classification in this case, off the top of my head. My preferred way of stating it is that the classification is now given by "homotopy actions" of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ on $H$, but it takes some effort to define and classify these more concretely. A special case that's relatively easy to talk about is that if $H$ is abelian then extensions are classified by a pair consisting of an action of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ on $H$ and a [cohomology class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_cohomology) in $H^2(\mathbb{Z}_2, H)$; this is enough to recover $\mathbb{Z}_4$, for example.

Comment: Well, this is not exactly a simple characterization (at least, not for someone who only took a basic course in group theory), but I will certainly read more about these topics you've mentioned. Thank you for your detailed answer.

Comment: There isn't a simple answer to your question!